# React - Axios/fetch takes so long to fetch data

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, fetch, postman

I have a simple MERN app, but when I try to fetch data, it takes up to 10-30 seconds to fetch data from database, only 100-500 records?

Here is the code, tried with fetch and axios.

```
 axios.get('/mybets/bets/1')
            .then(res => {
                let bets = res.data
                this.setState({ bets, isLoading: false })
            })
```

All my axios fetches takes long time, it's not only this. I also tried doing the API GET request in Insomnia/Postman and it took 10,3 seconds for 891 KB, which is a lot?

[image]

Here is the API Route

```
router.route("/bets/:id").get((req, res) => {
    Bet.find({ 'result': 'Pending' })
        .then(bets => res.json(bets))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

I'm using MongoDB Free Tier Cluster, but I didn't have these problems before, but should I upgrade?

Comment: well 890KB ? how does the response look like

Comment: well I think I found the mistake, I'm storing base64 strings for each entry in the db.. So stupid